# Kogrid: last column of grid is only partly visible

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

In koGrid 2.1.1:

Somehow, the last column of a grid is only partly visible.

I reproduced this bug with an example using the default config of the grid.

HTML:

```
<div class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.gridStyle {
border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Script:

```
function mainVm() {
    var self = this;
    this.myData = ko.observableArray([{
        name: "Moroni",
        age: 50
    }, {
        name: "Tiancum",
        age: 43
    }, {
        name: "Jacob",
        age: 27
    }, {
        name: "Nephi",
        age: 29
    }, {
        name: "Enos",
        age: 34
    }]);
    this.gridOptions = {
        data: self.myData
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new mainVm());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hUcc/1/

I cannot find what is causing this. Got any clue??

Comment: Works fine here (Chrome)

Comment: The header is cut off so I cant click it all the way, and the reason is a inline style width = 300 on .kgHeaderContainer

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate the scrolling bars' width and height, koGrid adds a temporary div in your body once the javascript file is loaded.

Therefore if you add the koGrid-x.js in the head of your HTML, the body wont be load and the scrolling bars measure will fail.

On the other hand, if you add the koGrid-x.js file at the end of your body element, it will be already loaded and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, in koGrid-2.1.1.debug.js, lines 2098 - 2114:

```
 var getWidths = function () {
        var $testContainer = $('');
        $testContainer.appendTo('body');
        // 1. Run all the following measurements on startup!
        //measure Scroll Bars
        $testContainer.height(100).width(100).css("position", "absolute").css("overflow", "scroll");
        $testContainer.append('');
        window.kg.domUtilityService.ScrollH = ($testContainer.height() - $testContainer[0].clientHeight);
        window.kg.domUtilityService.ScrollW = ($testContainer.width() - $testContainer[0].clientWidth);
        $testContainer.empty();
        //clear styles
        $testContainer.attr('style', '');
        //measure letter sizes using a pretty typical font size and fat font-family
        $testContainer.append('M');
        window.kg.domUtilityService.LetterW = $testContainer.children().first().width();
        $testContainer.remove();
    };
```

**window.kg.domUtilityService.ScrollH** and **window.kg.domUtilityService.ScrollW** are being calculated incorrectly. Fixed my problem by setting them both to 0. (zero)

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here and this fixed it however I noticed when scrolling clear to the right it throws the headers horizontal alignment off by about 10 pixels.  It may be those settings were there to correct that "drift".  Regardless, I think it is acceptable for now.